# Difference ec2:ResourceTag/${Tag Key} vs aws:ResourceTag/${TagKey}

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-iam

In the AWS policy conditions section, what is the difference between ec2:ResourceTag/${Tag Key} and aws: ResourceTag/${TagKey}?

I am trying to understand if there is a difference between adding to the conditions aws: ResourceTag/${TagKey} and ec2:ResourceTag/${Tag Key}?

Comment: chiming in, we are wondering the same about [AWS SecretsManager](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/service-authorization/latest/reference/list_awssecretsmanager.html#awssecretsmanager-secretsmanager_ResourceTag_tag-key) `secretsmanager:ResourceTag/tag-key`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`aws:ResourceTag` is an [AWS Global Condition Context Key](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_condition-keys.html), whereas `ec2:ResourceTag` is an [AWS Service-specific Key](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/service-authorization/latest/reference/list_amazonec2.html#amazonec2-policy-keys).

In the general case, Global identifiers should work in all services, but this is (was not in the past?) guaranteed, and you would need to verify if this was supported for the relevant service.

In this specific case, for EC2, they behave the same way, as you can see in the relevant documentation:

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/service-authorization/latest/reference/list_amazonec2.html#amazonec2-aws_ResourceTag___TagKey_
- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/service-authorization/latest/reference/list_amazonec2.html#amazonec2-ec2_ResourceTag___TagKey_

See also https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_condition-keys.html